# How to create AVD for Android Wear Square with 320x320 resolution?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, wear-os

I would like to create an AVD for Android Wear Square device with 320x320 resolutions (like the recent Sony SmartWatch).

However, I am not able to create it, AVD Manager in Android Studio only shows 280x280, and does not seem to find a way to change the resolution, even in Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried. If you click the `Clone Device` button, you can change the resolution

See the picture below:

[image]

Then, it will show on the phone tab

[image]

Comment: This works. The only catch is you need to choose No Skin, if the Wear Square skin is selected, it will revert back to 280x280.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to update your SDK to the latest version

> Update your SDK tools to version 23.0.0 or higher
>   The updated SDK tools enable you to build and test wearable apps.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html#GetTools

It might help to also install the Android Wear ARM/Intel System Images as well as update to the latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry misread the question, thought you meant you didn't have a Round device with 320x320 resolution, just a square.